# Keep the previous maximum value after the streak ends

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [110, 115, 112, 180, 150, 175, 160, 145, 200, 205, 208, 203, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 215],
        'b': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want. I want to create column `c`.

```
      a  b    c
0   110  1  110
1   115  1  115
2   112  0  115
3   180  1  180
4   150  0  180
5   175  1  180
6   160  0  180
7   145  0  180
8   200  1  200
9   205  1  205
10  208  1  208
11  203  0  208
12  206  1  208
13  207  1  208
14  208  1  208
15  209  1  209
16  210  1  210
17  215  1  215
```

When `df.a > df.a.shift(1)` `b` is 1 otherwise it is 0.

Steps needed:

a) Find where the streak of 1 in `b` ends.

b) Keep the maximum value of the streak.

c) Put that value in `c` until a greater value is found in `a`.

For example when 180 is found in `b`:

a) Row `3` has streak of 1.

b) Maximum value of the streak is 180.

c) `df.c = 180` until a greater value is found in `a`. In this case it is 200 at row `8`.

It was not easy to elaborate the problem. Maybe I have described the problem with wrong words. So If there are any questions feel free to ask in the comments.

And I really appreciate if you introduce a built-in way or a clean way to create column `b`. I put those 1 and 0s manually.

This is what I have tried. But it does not feel like a correct approach.

```
df['streak'] = df['b'].ne(df['b'].shift()).cumsum()
df['max'] = df.groupby('streak')['a'].max()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html):

```
df['c'] = df['a'].cummax()
```

Output:

```
      a  b    c
0   110  1  110
1   115  1  115
2   112  0  115
3   180  1  180
4   150  0  180
5   175  1  180
6   160  0  180
7   145  0  180
8   200  1  200
9   205  1  205
10  208  1  208
11  203  0  208
12  206  1  208
13  207  1  208
14  208  1  208
15  209  1  209
16  210  1  210
17  215  1  215
```